# compare if a value exists in a csv file

Tags: python, json, csv, pandas, comparison

I have a 200 MB CSV, file and a 4 GB json file in compressed format(300 MB when in compressed form). now I need to check if a particular field in json has a value which matches with any of the values in column 0 of the csv file. How can this be achieved in a fast as I have to do this for multiple json files, csv file being same. I hope using pandas would speed up things

After reading from CSV File the following datastructure is formed:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [1335063, 1339033, 1344453, 1392603, 1520033, 5342858, 5361498, 5534501, 5542881, 5552665, 5618397, 5824472, 5867442, 5908134, 5908134, 6203501, 6208411, 6209921, 6211681, 6212831, 6213691, 6287061, 6293811, 6387151, 6415771, 6508691, 6649281, 6673261, 6716441, 6782181, 6821631, 7710551, 9413871, 11280941, 11285381, 11762751, 11769381, 11854271, 11964831, 11995871, 12240091, 12541201, 12553471, 12633891, 12648021, 12834201, 12899581, 13177041, 13282401, 13290581, 13292951, 13297681, 14536901, 14592891, 14665721, 14843571, 15120821, 15127231, 15531511, 15969981, 16648561, 16808911, 16809381, 17019781, 17021721, 17224241, 17234921, 17327321, 17923721, 17930901, 18577181, 18606681, 19448911, 19557541, 20272801, 20286621, 20295001, 20351761, 21052471, 21062651, 21106501, 21578741, 22279401, 22312931, 23078211, 23164911, 24937351, 24988721, 26171811, 26188561, 26224001, 26379241, 26380531, 26383571, 26386251, 26388621, 27509171, 27825771, 28282901, 28998561, ...]
```

Now the data t be read from gzip file will be a json string and I can convert it with read_json. But I dont get how to see if the field 'id' in json is present in the lsit shown here

Comment: As written, this question is very vague. Can pandas access a single value in a DataFrame? Yes. Can pandas check if that value is in another DataFrame? Yes. Post some sample data if you want some concrete help.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas

magic_value = 11
df = pandas.DataFrame(np.random.random_integers(0, 12, size=(10,2)))

#     0   1
# 0   1   1
# 1   5   3
# 2  12  12
# 3  12   8
# 4  11   4
# 5  11  12
# 6   9   7
# 7   7   1
# 8   0  11
# 9   2   1

magic_value in df[0].values
# True
```

So just read in the JSON data with [`pandas.read_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-json-reader), get the value you want [(pandas indexing docs)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html), and go to town.